# What was your eureka moment, and how can I create one for myself?

Tags: research-process, academic-life

As a first-year graduate research student in science passing through several alternate "Peaks of Mount Stupid" and "valleys of despair", it would be great if some of you could share your experiences of how it actually feels like when you hit a "eureka moment". Does a point like that even exist? Sometimes it feels like we are so close to it, and then everything just breaks down like a castle of glass. What advice would you give to young researchers like me to avoid falling into these traps?

[image]

### What is a eureka moment?

I will use the example of searching for water in a desert. What a eureka moment is not, is when you think you found water but it's a mirage. What a eureka moment is, is when you suddenly find water and it is actually water, no exceptions.

P.S: The purpose of asking this here is that it would be genuinely helpful and inspiring to hear what people who have been through this before have to say about it. I believe this is a general issue in all fields, it's a problem that is rooted in the very idea of doing research. The question in itself is quite subjective, but I think there may be similarities in the ways people have coped with this, some tried and tested methods if you will.

Comment: What do you mean by 'eureka moment'? How exactly do you get close to it  or what makes you feel that way?

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Exchange is very poorly suited for "sharing anecdotes" type of questions.

Comment: "Eureka moments" feature heavily in writing about science because, much like the lone and possibly slightly mad genius, they make for good stories. That does not actually mean that this is how science operates for the most part. Unless by "eureka moment" you mean "I now understand some partial aspect of the problem that I have been thinking about for weeks slightly better", in which case the answer to your question (in math at least) is basically just "think hard about the problem for a long time and read what other people have written about it".

Comment: @AdamPřenosil Want to turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 5):

**In all of my career so far, I don't think I've ever had a "eureka moment." Real science doesn't normally work that way.**

In my experience, when working on a nasty problem one has lots of potential insights. The moment of insight is not the moment of discovery, however, it's the start of a grueling process of checking to see if the insight you think you've had is actually supported by your evidence. If it is, then eventually the data points begin to line up and the struggle to believe slowly fades into confidence and satisfaction.

The closest I've had to a eureka moment is when I look back at a line of research and suddenly realize that the actual important bits are not what we've been thinking they were, but something subtler and simpler: "We've worked really hard on all this stuff, and we should throw most of it away because only this bit over here was actually important." A great insight to have, and often quite valuable, but not one that lines up with the eureka sort of story.

I've also certainly had the opposite happen, however, in line with the quote attributed to Asimov:

> The most exciting phrase to hear in science, the one that heralds new discoveries, is not “Eureka” but “That’s funny...”

Rather than exciting, however, I would call it terrifying, as for me that has often involved having pried up a metaphorical rock and discovered [a horrible mess undermining many results](https://doi.org/10.1038/nbt.2891) [that will take the field](https://doi.org/10.1049/enb.2017.0004) [a decade or more to straighten out](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-023-32481-z).

**Bottom line: don't look for eureka moments. Look for gradually deepening knowledge and confidence in what you know.**

Answer (score 1):

Eureka moments can't be planned or created. They are pure serendipity. If you could plan for it you wouldn't need to have it.

[Archimedes:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_effect) "Now if I just get in this bath, I will suddenly and unexpectedly understand displacement."

On the other hand, a skilled teacher can create the conditions in which students might have such a moment of sudden insight. But that would be for things already well understood, not for the as-yet unknown.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you have ideas that you found later had already been carried through? Does that happen more-or-less regularly?
2. Did you have *the One* great idea that filled you with utter excitement? Whether executed to the end or not?
3. Did you have the moment of lucid insight where something that was  opaque to you until then suddenly became clear as a crisp winter morning?
4. Did you have a slow growth of understanding where things become clearer as you work through them, but not with a massive jump?
5. Are you a "methodical worker" (i.e. marathon runner) as opposed to a "burst worker" (sprinter)?
6. Do you have the patience working difficult problems through until success?

If the answer to any of questions 1-3 is "yes", you have experienced an "eureka" moment. Try to capture the sensation you had then and you will now recognize when it happens.

If your response to 4-6 is "yes", you are more likely to not experience insight at a flash, but in slow progress. Don't expect eureka moments. That does not mean that you are less successful.

In fact, even people who experience eureka moments typically precede them by slow methodical work. Insight is not magic. It is the coalescence of a major body of work. And it usually happens in a moment of relaxation, when, to use Freudspeak, the subconscious feels safe in telling the conscious brain its rambling thoughts.

There is no guaranteed way to get this. But it does help to work methodically on consolidating understanding, push at the edges of your knowledge to stretch your comfort zone, look beyond them to see what's out there, and finally give yourself space to relax.

Good luck!